# Is space weather, solar-terrestrial physics, etc., on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this question on-topic?

*[What, if any, plans have been made for handling events like a geomagnetic reversal?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-if-any-plans-have-been-made-for-handling-events-like-a-geomagnetic-revers)*

I'd say this is rather a question on geophysics, space weather, solar-terrestrial physics, the effects space has on Earth.  I don't really see it as a space *exploration* question.  What do others think — is it on-topic?

Comment: Possibly related to [Where is our demarcation line between Space Exploration and Physics?](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/12/where-is-our-demarcation-line-between-space-exploration-and-physics)

Comment: Note that the linked question was edited since I posted this meta-question.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not really see it as a space exploration question, then we are in trouble, I guess. Geophysics, the question of space weather and solar-terrestrial physics are deeply liked to each other. Those are actually overlapping categories. Yes, your example question could equally be asked in physics, biology, geosciences or somewhere else, but it does fit into space *exploration* too. In this example, the question boils down to the issue of how our modern society, driven by electronic devices and **relying** on satellites would handle the next upcoming reversal and its side effects. It also implies the understanding of the reversal in the first place, including measurements and monitoring in space. Therefore, it is a perfectly valid question to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about Space Weather are absolutely on topic, as long as it relates to Space Exploration. If it relates purely to the science behind it, then it wouldn't be as related.

On Topic:

- What radiation tolerances for solar flares are needed for a deep space probe?
- What is the difference in radiation requirements between LEO and GEO orbits?
- How does the sunspot cycle affect radiation loads?
- How can space weather be observed from orbiting spacecraft?

Off topic:

- What causes the 11 year old sunspot cycle?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if the question

- A. Is directly related to the effects of something on space exploration
- or B. Is related to the effects of sace exploration on something,

Then it is alright.

Therefore, your example would probably be off-topic. Voting to close...